# Weird usage of Array.of() and Array.from()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

There are two new methods of `Array` in `ES6`, `Array.of()` and `Array.from()`. The difference usage of them are mentioned in this [page](https://gist.github.com/rwaldron/1074126).

However, I am confused with the usage of `Array.of` in this [line](https://gist.github.com/rwaldron/1074126#file-array-goodies-js-L127)

```
// usage of Array.of
console.log(
    Array.of( "things", "that", "aren't", "currently", "an", "array" )
); // ["things", "that", "aren't", "currently", "an", "array"]
```

What if we do it as below,

```
console.log(
    [ "things", "that", "aren't", "currently", "an", "array" ]
); // ["things", "that", "aren't", "currently", "an", "array"]
```

The same result we can get as `console.log(Array.of(...))`. Any advantage of using `Array.of` here?

Also confused with the usage of `Array.from` in this [line](https://gist.github.com/rwaldron/1074126#file-array-goodies-js-L42)

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
console.log(
    Array.from( divs )
);
```

What if there is no `Array.from` in the above codes.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(Array.from(arr)); // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(arr); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Any advantage of using `Array.from` here?

Comment: There is no advantage of using `Array.of` over an array literal. There is an advantage of using `Array.of` over `new Array`.

Comment: There is no advantage of using `Array.from` on an array. There is an advantage of using `Array.from` on an array-like object such as a `NodeList`.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### [Array.of()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of)

Brendan eich said ([Source](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2011-July/015841.html)):

> Dmitry A. Soshnikov wrote:
>
> > Brendan Eich wrote:
> >
> > > So the goal of Array.of is to provide a constructor that, unlike
> > >       Array, does not have that insane special case for Array(42), which
> > >       presets length (and hints to implementations to preallocate) but
> > >       leaves holes in [0, length).
> >
> > I still don't see how it will help in manual enumeration of the same
> >     items which may be directly passed to brackets of array initialiser.
> >     We enumerate (by hands) items here, right? -- `Array.of(1, 2, 3)`. And
> >     we enumerate items here (by hands also) -- `[1, 2, 3]`. The difference
> >     is that the second case syntactically more elegant and sugared and
> >     also doesn't require non-needed function activation with allocating
> >     call-stack frame, etc.
>
> That's all true, but beside the point. The use-case is when you can't
>   write a literal, because you are passing a function-that-constructs as
>   a funarg, and the eventual caller may pass only one number arg, or
>   several args. In that case, Array will not do the right thing in the
>   one-number-arg case.
>
> That's the reason for `Array.of`.

Example:

```js
// Array.of(42) creates an array with a single element, 42, whereas Array(42) creates an array with 42 elements, each of which is undefined.
console.log(new Array(42));
console.log(Array.of(42));
```

#### [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

The `Array.from()` method creates a new Array instance from an **array-like or iterable object**.

1. array-like objects (objects with a length property and indexed elements)
2. iterable objects (objects where you can get its elements, such as Map and Set).

For example:

```js
var m = new Map([[1, 2], [2, 4], [4, 8]]);
console.log("m is:");
console.log(m);

var _from = Array.from(m);
console.log("After .from: ");
console.log(_from);
```